# Tkinter - how do I change the title?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How do I change the title for this, I tried the way I know but it wont work.
just so you know the code is a macro clicker

```
#from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageOps
import pyautogui
import time
import tkinter as tk
from numpy import *



class Coordinates():
#Coordinates can be changed to wherever you want to AutoClick
    replayBtn = (100,350)


# close button (woah)
class YourGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # inherit tkinter's window methods
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        tk.Label(self, text="ENTER X:").grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.inputX = tk.Entry(self)
        self.inputX.grid(row=0, column=1)

        tk.Label(self, text="ENTER Y:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.inputY = tk.Entry(self)
        self.inputY.grid(row=0, column=4)

        tk.Button(self, text="convert", command=self.do_conversion).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

        tk.Button(self, text="exit!", command=self.EXITME).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def EXITME(self):
        exit(0)  # crashed prog so it closes
        # strtoint("crashmE!")

    def do_conversion(self):
        y = self.inputY.get()
        x = self.inputX.get()

        running = True
        try:
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
        except:
            print("Invalid point")
            exit(0)
            # strtoint("crashmE!")
        while running:
            pyautogui.click(x, y)


your_gui = YourGUI()
your_gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is a minimum character limit for a reason. Do not copy paste text to try and circumvent this requirement. For the simple title change you could have found that all over stack overflow. In the method that inherits from `Tk()` you can do `self.title("any title")`.

Comment: What "this" are you talking about?

Comment: Mike - SMT you do know that it doesn't work with my code it adds another window instead of changing the title

Comment: `self.title("any title")` works in my Windows box with Python 3.7.1 and Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are meaning a setting title of your tkinter window by "this". You have several options.

**Option 1**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    your_gui = YourGUI()
    your_gui.title('My Title') # Set title
    your_gui.mainloop()
```

**Option 2**

```
 def __init__(self):
        # inherit tkinter's window methods
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('My Title')  # Set title
        .......
        tk.Button(self, text="exit!", command=self.EXITME).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Both options should work in Python 3.7.1 and Python 2.7.5